# Firefox: Add search engine programmatically and use it right away

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, search-engine

I have developed a Firefox addon that broke with Firefox 24.

My addon adds a search engine to the search bar, based on some user settings. For adding the search engine, I use [addEngine()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserSearchService#addEngine%28%29) from `nsIBrowserSearchService`.

Until Firefox 23, this function also selected the added engine, so users could use it right away. From Firefox 24, this behavior stopped: The engine is being added but not selected anymore.

However, the [documentation still says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserSearchService#addEngine%28%29):

> ... the new engine will be used right away automatically.

What can I do to force the new engine to be used right away also in Firefox 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little workaround would be to change directly the preference for the default search engine after you added your new one:

```
browser.search.defaultenginename
```

This preference takes the exact name of the search engine.

Additionally, there's more information on adding a search engine in [this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/draft_Search_Extension_Tutorial#Adding_a_New_Search_Engine):

```js
function startup(data, reason) {
    firstRun = reason == ADDON_INSTALL;
    // Re-select the search engine if this is the first run
    // or we're being re-enabled.
    selectSearch = firstRun || reason == ADDON_ENABLE;

    // Only add the engine if it doesn't already exist.
    if (!Services.search.getEngineByName(ENGINE_DETAILS.name)) {
        Services.search.addEngineWithDetails.apply(Services.search,
            ["name", "iconURL", "alias", "description", "method", "url"].map(
                function (k) ENGINE_DETAILS[k]))
    }

    let engine = Services.search.getEngineByName(ENGINE_DETAILS.name);

    // If the engine is not hidden and this is the first run, move
    // it to the first position in the engine list and select it
    if (selectSearch && !engine.hidden) {
        Services.search.moveEngine(engine, 0);
        Services.search.currentEngine = engine;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. However, I am adding the search engine in the [startup()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) function. I now tried to also change the preference in there as you suggested but it has no effect. It has an effect though, if I make some of the already existing engines the default one (e.g. "Bing"). So probably, the added engine is not yet known during the startup() process.)

Comment: @GeorgJaehnig. Have you tried [this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/draft_Search_Extension_Tutorial#Adding_a_New_Search_Engine) of adding the search engine?

Comment: Now I have found the solution! The problem was that I used `addEngine()`. This function first downloads the Opensearch-XML-file via the web, which takes some milliseconds. So obviously, the engine is not yet there in the next JS code lines.
Instead, I use now `addEngineWithDetails()` which adds the engine right away. Thanks to your link, Filipe, I could copy that approach.

Comment: @GeorgJaehnig. Great! Glad to help. I added the approach to my answer to make it easier to find.